# mshtml.HTMLTableCell has Incorrect innerText value

Tags: c#, html, mshtml, innertext

When I try to parse `HTMLTableCell` the `innerText` value is incorrect and it seem that I'm getting the class name instead of the text.

Now the strange thing is that when I look at the cell (in VS2010) in debug I see the proper value what am I doing wrong?

Further investigation brought this up, when I look up the values in VS2010 it looks like this 
**cell.innerText** is **"center time"** and **((mshtml.HTMLTableCellClass)(cell)).innerText** is **"23:45"**. Problem is that it won't compile when I cast and I to mshtml.HTMLTableCellClass so I have to use the interface (why is that?)

see code below:

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = MainBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;

if (doc != null)
{

    mshtml.HTMLTable table = doc.getElementById("ecEventsTable") as mshtml.HTMLTable;

    List<List<string>> textRows = new List<List<string>>();

    foreach (mshtml.HTMLTableRow row in table.rows)
    {
        if (row != null && row.id != null && row.id.Contains("eventRowId"))
        {
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();

            foreach (mshtml.HTMLTableCell cell in row.cells)
            {
                string text = cell.innerText;
                if (text != null && text != "" && text != " ")
                {
                    if (text.Contains("\r\n"))
                        text = text.Replace("\r\n", "");

                    temp.Add(cell.innerText);
                }
            }

            if (temp.Count > 0)
                textRows.Add(temp);
        }
    }

    foreach (var row in textRows)
    {
        string str = String.Join(" ", row);
    }
}
```

}

HTML example row:

`<tr id="eventRowId_34599" onclick="javascript:changeEventDisplay(34599, this, 'overview');" event_timestamp="2014-02-24 01:30:00" event_attr_id="752">
<td class="center time">01:30</td>
<td class="flagCur"><span title="China" class=" ceFlags China">&nbsp;</span>CNY</td>
<td title="" class="sentiment"><i class="newSiteIconsSprite grayFullBullishIcon middle"></i><i class="newSiteIconsSprite grayEmptyBullishIcon middle"></i>
<i class="newSiteIconsSprite grayEmptyBullishIcon middle"></i></td>

<td class="left event">China House Prices (YoY)</td>
<td title="" class="bold act blackFont" id="eventActual_34599">9.6%</td>
<td class="fore" id="eventForecast_34599">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="prev blackFont" id="eventPrevious_34599">9.9%</td>
<td class="diamond" id="eventRevisedFrom_34599">&nbsp;</td>                            </tr>`

Comment: So `string text = cell.innerText;` is incorrect? Can you add example HTML.

Comment: @AlexK. Small example cell: `<td class="center time">01:30</td>` in line `string text = cell.innerText;` text is "center time" instead of "01:30".

Comment: Have you tried cell.innerHtml instead?

Comment: @Frankenscarf I tried innerHTml same exact problem

Comment: **Comment:** I develop in VS2010 (.NET 4) the mshtml version that I'm referencing is 7.0.3300.0 in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common maybe I use an old version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using **mshtml.HTMLTableCell** I use **mshtml.IHTMLElement** and now it works.

code after the fix (see old version in the question):

```
foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement cell in row.cells)
{
    string text = cell.innerText;

    if (text != null && text != "" && text != " ")
    {
        if (text.Contains("\r\n"))
            text = text.Replace("\r\n", "");

        temp.Add(text);
    }
}
```